# Eclipse gradle error: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

My `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' // version defined in setting.gradle file
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' // version defined in setting.gradle file
    id 'java'
}
```

[image: gradle.build plugins]

presents the following error message:

```
Could not run build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-bin.zip'
```

[image: gradle.build error]

I have changed the initial `gradle-wrapper.properties` distribution url (6.6.1) to a one working with other projects in the same eclipse workspace (7.1.1):

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

but when I Refresh Gradle Project, the error remains.

I haven't been able to find the solution in posts describing similar issues.

My `setting.gradle` pluginManagement looks like this:

```
pluginManagement {
    plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.5.RELEASE'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
    }
}
```

And the version of Eclipse that I am running is:

- Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
- Build id: 20181214-0600

Comment: Why are you trying this with an Eclipse build over 2 years older than your intended gradle version?

Comment: Good question, I haven't been brave enough to update yet

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Remove plugins section from `build.gradle` file
2. Refresh Gradle Project. The following error is displayed now:
   [image: build.gradle error]
3. Add back plugins section from `build.gradle` file
4. Refresh Gradle Project. The error icon is gone:
   [image: build.gradle ok]

Comment: i checked build.gradle and saw conflict files, deleting from disk and re-getting so build.gradle had no conflict did it for me.